# Gateway with colliding networks

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

I have an Ubuntu-box as a gateway with two interfaces. The first one (eth0) is the internal network and has the following address:

```
eth0: 192.168.1.1/24
```

The second one is connected to a router from an ISP, to which I don't have access! And, alas, it has 192.168.1.1 as address... So I ended up choosing the following for eth1:

```
eth1: 192.168.1.240/32
```

Then adding

```
route add 192.168.1.1 eth1
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
```

But this only works if I change the IP of my gateway on eth0 to 192.168.1.2 or something else. Is there a way to define the routing while keeping 192.168.1.1 on my gateway, too?

PS: Yes, I could reconfigure my internal network to something else, but as there is a Windows-domain-server on it, I don't want to do that.

Comment: Cmon, this is Linux - there has to be another way! BTW usually I do have different subnets - just this time it would be very hard, as I have the PDC on the 192.168.1.0/24 and more hardcoded IPs than I'd like to.

Comment: i don't say you use iptables you implement this with `ip route` or `route command`.

Comment: The easiest fix, I think, is to insert a new, two-NIC system between eth1 and the ISP router, allocating a new (non-conflicting, this time!) network number for the eth1-NewSystem link. You won't be able to ping the ISP router from your system, but that's a minor issue. If you don't have a system to spare, you can probably accomplish the same thing with a VM running on the host.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be to use two different subnets for your network, one for internal use and one for public/wan use, putting two interfaces in the same subnet will only cause you trouble. 
If you don't want to change the IP for the Windows DC, I suggest that you split the /24 to two /25, and use one for lower /25 for your internal net, and the upper /25 for your internet/wan connection.

Comment: Well, I have hardcoded IPs in the 192.168.1.0/25-range, so I can't put that easily to 192.168.1.128/25... And I don't have access to the router, so I can't put that in the 192.168.1.128/25, neither :(

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer from Mark Plotnick the best:

Insert a system with two NICs that hides the router from the gatewayor

or

Install a virtual machine on the gateway that is attached to the `eth0` and an internal interface with another subnet. Then route all traffic through the internal interface. Probably LXC should be most easy, though I never tried it out.